# How to check in Ajax and JavaScript, if mail is sent or not with PHP mailer

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, phpmailer

I have a contact form which send emails successfully with PHP Mailer. I check my form with JavaScript and AJAX call.

My AJAX call is not working as expected. I don't know how can I check with AJAX if mail is successfully send and then display div for that.
Mailer works fine, and also JS verification works great, but I don't know how to check if mail is sent or not in AJAX.

Please take a look at my code.

HTML FORM

```
                                <form id="contact-form" class="contact">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" name="name" id="fullname" placeholder="Fullname">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email adress">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                <button id="gumb" type="button" class="btnc" onclick="validateContact();">Send</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>

                        </div>      

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div id="response_brought"></div><!-- This will display the response from the server -->
                            <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT with AJAX (**part where is problem**)
I don't know how to set that it goes to "AJAX call" when all input fields are successfully validated and THEN ALSO in AJAX call check if mail is sent or not and then display those divs with mails sent or mail not sent...

```
function validateContact() {
"use strict";
var valid = true;

var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
var formData = {
    fullname: $("#fullname").val(),
    email: $("#email").val(),
    message: $("#message").val(),
};
var fullname = $("#fullname").val();
var emailreg = $("#email").val();
var message = $("#message").val();

    //dataString = {'fullname': fullname, 'email': email,   'message': message, 'submitted': '1'};

if (fullname === "") { //Validation against empty field for fullname
    $("#response_brought").html('<br clear="all"><div class="form_info" align="left">Please enter your fullname in the required field to proceed. Thanks.</div>');
    $("#fullname").focus();
    valid = false;
} else if (emailreg === "") { //Validation against empty field for email address
    $("#response_brought").html('<br clear="all"><div class="form_info" align="left">Please enter your email address in the required email field to proceed. Thanks.</div>');
    $("#email").focus();
    valid = false;
} else if (reg.test(emailreg) === false) { //Validation for working email address
    $("#response_brought").html('<br clear="all"><div class="form_info" align="left">Sorry, your email address is invalid. Please enter a valid email address to proceed. Thanks.</div>');
    $("#email").focus();
    valid = false;
} else if (message === "") { //Validation against empty field for email message
    $("#response_brought").html('<br clear="all"><div class="form_info" align="left">Please enter your message in the required message field to proceed. Thanks.</div>');
    $("#message").focus();
    valid = false;
} 
valid = true;

$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "sendemail.php", 
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: formData, 
    success:function(formData){ 
        if(formData.success){
            $(".contact-form").slideUp(500); 
            $("#response_brought").html('<br clear="all"><div class="form_info" align="left">Thank you for your email.</div>');
        }
        else{
            $(".contact-form").slideUp(500); 
            $("#response_brought").html('<br clear="all"><div class="form_info" align="left">Sorry, mail is not working at the moment.</div>');
        }
    }, error:function (){} 
});
```

And sendemail.php

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

require_once 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require_once 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require_once 'phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
$mail->SMTPAuth   = True;


$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
$mail->Port = '587';

$fullname     = $_POST['fullname'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

if (!empty($fullname) && !empty($email) && !empty($message)) {

try {
    $mail->setFrom('myemail');
    $mail->addAddress('myemail');
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Mail poslan iz spletnega obrazca';
    $mail->Body = "Ime: " . $_POST["fullname"] . "<br> Email: " . $_POST["email"] .         "<br>";
    $mail->Body .= $message;
    $mail->send();

    $output = json_encode(array('success' => true));
    echo $output;

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        $output = json_encode(array('success' => false));
        echo $output;

    }
```

Comment: First you have to set ajax datatype to json, then in the mailer you need to echo the $output variable. You can even add to your return array the message you want to display.

Comment: You just need to add `header('Content-type: application/json');` to your sendmail.php file as well as echo the `$output` var.

Comment: Your title is not searchable, pls replace "Expected" part with the real problem.

Comment: I edited my code now (ajax header, ajax success and echoed results in PHP) in my question. 
It is still not working. It doesn't show the success message that mail has been sent. I recieve mail but that html whic i want to display doesn't display..  Probrem is i guess in my sucess function or in echoing in php... Please take a look